# How to access the Exvcel Plugin " Refresh from Dynamics 365" using Python

Tags: python, excel, dynamics-crm

I wish to run the Python script where it opens the Excel and clicks on "Refresh from Dynamics365" instead of "RefreshAll".
[Excel view of this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foJsK.png)

What can I add so that the Python calls for it?

Here is my current code

````
import time


xlapp = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open('Excel file location')
xlapp.visible = True
time.sleep(20)
def refresh_excel():
 wb.RefreshAll()-- I need to change to "refresh from Dynamics 365 button"
 time.sleep(20)
 wb.Save()

while True:  
 refresh_excel()
 time.sleep(7200)
 wb.Save() ```
````

Comment: Any help please!!

Comment: I am not sure if this is even possible, is there any trigger been provided by Microsoft to catch it and perform your operation?

Comment: Well so far the trigger what I am currently doing is clicking "manually" on "refresh from Dynamics 365" and then entering my credential so that it connects to the CRM , after that I am excuting th above script where it keeps " refreshall" , but here the issue is after 9 hours the CRM disconnets (time out) so the only way is to click on "refresh from Dynamics 365 " so the timeout doesn't happen.